# Artifactory Failed to export , Binary provider has no content

Tags: binary, export, backup, artifactory

When trying to backup or export the JFrog Artifactory, the backup folder is created.
But the System log shows multiple errors like:
2019-12-23 17:31:07,026 [art-exec-5] [ERROR] (o.a.r.d.i.DbExportBase:123) - Failed to export '/data/backups/20191223.172751.tmp/repositories/repo1.maven.org-cache/org/apache/httpcomponents/project/7/project-7.pom' due to:Binary provider has no content for 'c486760d8e0eafe8d4932450e386c2805364f782': Binary provider has no content for 'c486760d8e0eafe8d4932450e386c2805364f782'

Answer (score 0):

This error is printed when the actual binary file is missing from the Artifactory storage location (by default, $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data/filestore/). You shouldn't be able to download the same artifact (repo1.maven.org-cache/org/apache/httpcomponents/project/7/project-7.pom) as well ad the actual content is missing. This however shouldn't fail the backup of the repository/system, it just an error message indicates that the content of this artifact does not exist.